# Directory.Exists return true but Directory.GetDirectories returns empty list

Tags: c#, asp.net, io, azure-web-app-service

I'm struggling with following issue:

- Directory.Exists - returns true
- DirectoryInfo - can display info about directory
- Directory.GetDirectories - returns empty list

Debugger watches:
[image: Debugger watches]

Comment: Does the `..\Default` directory contain any directories? I would wager that it does not since it is returning a `Length = 0`, the other two methods, are returning `true` that `..\Default` directory exists and information about that directory.

Comment: Please show you actual code with parameter values used in the 3 cases. I suspect that `GetDirectories` lists the sub-directories inside the one displayed by `Directory.Exists` or `DirectoryInfo`. This means that the directory exists, but that it does not contain sub-directories.

Comment: @RyanWilson default directory should contain FirstLevelDir directory inside. And as you can see in DirectoryInfo object it exists.

Comment: Can you show the directory existing in a screenshot of Windows Explorer?

Comment: @ChristopherSchwarz You still haven't answered the question, and that is, does `..\Default` contain any directories? You haven't bothered to show a picture of what you see when you open that directory in File Explorer. Perhaps that directory existed when you placed that in your Watch and by the time you did the call to `Directory.GetDirectories` that directory was moved/deleted.

Comment: @DavidG it's a azure web app. I checked in Azure SCM and those files and directories don't exist - which is desired behaviour... question is why those methods still see them.

Comment: @RyanWilson sorry for misunderstanding. I forgot to mention it. Those directories were removed about 10 minutes before I called those methods. I can only see it on Azure File Explorer and there I can see only "Default" directory without any others. So the question is why Directory.Exists returns true for subdirectories of Default?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the same path for `Directory.Exists` and for `Directory.GetDirectories` you are getting a different kind of information

```cs
string path = @"C:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot\ms-cache\Default";
bool exists = Directory.Exists(path);        // --> true
int length = Directory.GetDirectories(path); // --> 0
```

- `exists == true` means that the `Default` directory exists.
- `length == 0`    means that the `Default` directory does not contain sub-directories.

To confirm that there is a directory with `GetDirectories`, you must call it for the parent directory

```
string parentDir = @"C:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot\ms-cache";
int length = Directory.GetDirectories(parentDir ); // --> > 0
```

Now `length` is at least 1, but might be greater.

Comment: Look at the screenshot, the second watch shows that the subdirectory exists.

Comment: @ChristopherSchwarz, We still don't know how you called these methods. Please show your actual code. E.g., `GetDirectories` has 3 overloads. Which one did you use, with which arguments?

Comment: I am not the OP, just pointing out the the 2nd watch (and the last) both say the directory exists.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes look on the screenshot, in left column you can see which methods and params are used to call.